# How to use orWhere in Doctrine | Return user who have ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository, symfony4

I want to return user who have `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER`

I have did this in repository :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.roles IN (:val)')
        ->setParameter('val','["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"]')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

But nothing is returned... 
How to solve this probleme?

> ps: I have a user with ROLES : ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER

Comment: Same probleme..

Comment: this is example of user : [{"roles":["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use orWhere in Doctrine 2:**

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.roles LIKE :val')
        ->setParameter('val','%ROLE_ADMIN%')
        ->orWhere('u.roles LIKE :val2')
        ->setParameter('val2', '%ROLE_USER%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Also You can use like this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.roles LIKE :val')
        ->orWhere('u.roles LIKE :val2')
        ->setParameters(array('val2' => '%ROLE_USER%', 'val' => '%ROLE_ADMIN%'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks Its work, but how when i want more Roles not only ROLE_ADMIN? For example u.roles Like %ROLE_ADMIN% or %ROLE_USER% => How to do this please?